# JavaScript: How to save html text in HTML5 localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to save my appended html() text, every time i click the button it should be store in HTML 5 local storage.

```
$('#add_new_criteria').on('click',function(){
     $('#cyc_append').html(': Add new another criteria');
     localStorage.setItem( ???? );

});
```

Comment: Should new `html` overwrite existing `html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#add_new_criteria').on('click',function(){
     $('#cyc_append').html(': Add new another criteria');
     localStorage.setItem('textKey', $('#cyc_append').html());

});
```

> The first argument is the identifier you’ll later use to get the data
>   out again. The second is the data you want to store.

Read more on [**localStorage**](http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/)

Comment: If you want to have only newest value, then use static hardcoded value as your textKey. If you want to have 'history', then your textKey could be timestamp that you can generate like this - new Date().getTime();

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis Yes that can be done to maintain history of all html set

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.setItem('key','value');`

you can check result in Chrome Console -> Resources -> Local Storage whether it is getting saved.

Refer following link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage